# Purity of the Picard group for normal schemes.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a normal connected noetherian scheme of finite dimension and let $Z \subset X$ be a closed subset of codimension at least 2. Is the canonical map
$$Pic(X) \to Pic(X \setminus Z)$$
an isomorphism?

Background: The statement is true for regular schemes $X$, as there we can express $Pic(X)$ in terms of Weil Divisors up to rational equivalence. Motivated by this and the fact that normal schemes are regular in codimension 1, one might hope that one can extend this statement to normal schemes.

Comment: I don't think so : if $X$ is normal, then $\operatorname{Pic}(X)\rightarrow CH^1(X)$ is injective, the same holds for $\operatorname{Pic}(X\setminus Z)\rightarrow CH^1(X\setminus Z)$. This shows that at least the map $\operatorname{Pic}(X)\rightarrow\operatorname{Pic}(X\setminus Z)$ is injective. Now I don't think it is onto : for if $Z$ is the singular locus, $\operatorname{Pic}(X\setminus Z)\rightarrow CH^1(X\setminus Z)$ is an isomorphism, by diagram chase it seems that this would imply that $Pic(X)\simeq CH^1(X)$ which is wrong.

Comment: To expand on @Roland comment, take $X$ be the normal surface in 3-space given by $x^2-yz=0$ and $Z$ be the origin. Then $\mathrm{Pic}\, X=0$, but $\mathrm{Pic}\, (X-Z)=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.